# Angular change component state from a service when route changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ui-router, observable, ngrx

I have a component called `profile`. It gets its data from `user.service`. Problem is that it does not change when the Route changes (on click, using 'routerLink'); I want to bring in new data from the service every time the route changes. I have tried Subscribing to the route param observable. But it returns an Observable of an Observable (I'm sure there are better ways of doing things).

#### Here's My Code

```js
// imports ...

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  $user: Observable<User>;
    
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    
  ngOnInit() {
    // UserService.getSingleUser(string); returns Observable<User>;
    
    // Method 1 (Tried. failed)
    this.$user = this.userService.getSingleUser(this.router.url.sibstring(1));
    
    // Method 2 (Tried, failed)
    this.route.params.pipe(
      map(params => params.username),
      map(username => this.userService.getSingleUser(username))
    ).subscribe(response => {
      this.$user = response;
    });
    
    
    this.$user.subscribe({
      next: console.log,
      error: console.warn
    });
  }
}
```

> [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/aetherwebdev/4b35d91201c942ded0aa360e996627ca)

Comment: What do you mean route changes, routeLink? Please paste your route module for more details.

Comment: The Profile component is rendered using Router. and It's path is as follows. `{path:":username", component: ProfileComponent}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely looking for a combination of your second method and [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) ([check this](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) for a visualized explanation).
It will allow you to exchange the running observable stream with a new inner one, in this case `userService.getSingleUser`.

```
this.$user = this.route.params.pipe(
  map(params => params.username),
  switchMap(username => this.userService.getSingleUser(username))
);
```

The `$user`-observable should store the result from `userService.getSingleUser`. Not that you most likely want to double check if `params.username` exists. Depending on your route structures this may result in `undefined`.
If you subscribe to the observable within your template, you will not have to worry about destroying the stream afterwards. If you plan to use `.subscribe` within your `.ts` file, remember to destroy the subscription properly, otherwise this will result in a leak.

Comment: Thank You Very Much for the answer. Would you be so kind to elaborate a little bit on what is a switchMap and how it works, Thanks Again.

Comment: You're welcome. I added link to a documentation for `switchMap`. I am sure you will understand what it does much better by reading that article over me explaining it :)